# Mapping unit disc onto upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

How can I map the unit disc onto the upper half plane?

I tried mapping $(1,i,-1)\rightarrow(1,0,\infty)$ using cross-ratio:
$z\rightarrow \frac{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}$, but didn't give me the right answer...

Answer (score 3):

Do you know how to conformally map the upper half plane to the unit disc? If so, you can take the inverse of this using matrix algebra.

An example of conformal map from the upper half plane to the unit disc is:

$$z \to \frac{z-i}{z+i}$$

Comment: Nope, I don't know how to ''select'' the right triples $(z_2,z_3,z_4)$. I think that's my problem

Comment: edited with an example.

Comment: What are the triples you chose? And why?

Comment: I want to take the boundary of the upper half plane to the boundary of the disc, so I want everything on the vertical line to have norm $1$ in the image. I choose to send $i$ to $0$ as the new center of the circle, and since I want points on the horizontal line to go to norm $1$, this forces me to make the denominator $z+i$, since $-i$ is symmetric to $i$ across the line.

Comment: I learned it like this: the cross ratio which maps $(z_2,z_3,z_4)\rightarrow (1,0,\infty)$ is your axiom and making use of inverse and composition, I can map anything to anything. I think your method is better, but I don't ''see'' it happening. E.g. wat do you define as the boundary of the upper half plane? And what do you mean with ''the vertical line''

Comment: The cross ratio is a framework for doing these things, but you need to be able to make an intelligent guess based on some geometry. The boundary of the upper half plane is the horizontal axis -- this is the topological boundary.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get yet how you came to your answer. What I do make  of it, is that the transform mapping the unit disc to the upper half plane is not unique?

Comment: It's certainly far from unique. You can just pre-compose it with any of the conformal maps of the disc to itself (of which there are many, e.g. rotations)

Comment: Can you maybe show me some simple figure to understand what you're saying?

Comment: Btw, what I was proposing in my initial question: is that wrong?